# php/wordpress include a file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, include

This question is regarding `wordpress`.

I have two variables `$random_n` and `$adcount` declared in each of `index.php` , `archieve.php`, `search.php` and `single.php` files at the very first line.

The variables are declared as follows:

```
<?php $random_n = randomNumber();?> 
<?php $adcount = 1; ?>
```

`randomNumber()` is a function inside function.php.

If I move those variables to `header.php` and remove them from all these files, it stops working. :/ The variables can't be found in `index.php`, `archieve.php`, `search.php`, `single.php` if they are placed in `header.php`

I've also tried putting this code inside a new file and including that file to `index.php`, `archieve.php`, `search.php`, and `single.php`, but it hadn't helped as well.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the description of your question what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is somehow related to your blog configuration, you should use the wordpress option API to build this (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) , search for option).

If your variable is random (your function name hints that) a way to work around this would be using [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to store those values.

A good tutorial on how to use session variables in wordpress can be found here: 
http://www.myguysolutions.com/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-the-use-of-sessions-on-your-wordpress-blog/

Answer (score 1):

Type in `var_dump($random_n)` into the beginning of `index.php` and post the output, please.

One possible reason is that your `index`, `search` and so on are included inside the function that does not share the scope with `header.php`, so your vars are just outside of the scope. It might help if you declare them `global` both in `header.php` and your working files. But that's not a good idea.

Better solution would be to introduce some `Registry` object ([Registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html)) and use it.